# how datadog montiors can query for a ratio

Tags: datadog

In datadog I wish to create a log monitor where the query gets the ratio of logs fulfilling a certain criteria to logs fulfilling another set of criteria. I already know how to get a count of both kinds of logs (largely through count *),  but does anyone know how to actually get these two values as a ratio, so I can set a threshold to a relevant percentage?